# firebase-x@ionic 4 not showing push messages (FCM)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ionic-framework

I created this code in my app console:

**app.compontent.ts**

```js
this.firebaseX.getToken().then(token => console.log('PUSH_TOKEN: GET_TOKEN: ', token))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.firebaseX.grantPermission().then(hasPermission => console.log(hasPermission ? 'granted' : 'denied'));

    this.firebaseX.onApnsTokenReceived().subscribe(token => console.log('PUSH_TOKEN: IOS_TOKEN: ' + token));
}

this.firebaseX.onMessageReceived().subscribe(message => console.log(message));
```

xCode configuration:
[image: xCode]

Chrome console after sending push message via firebase console:
[image: android console - push received]

xCode Console when app init:

```
2020-01-19 17:09:22.816015+0100 myApp[8896:2663293] registerForRemoteNotifications
2020-01-19 17:09:22.816107+0100 myApp[8896:2663293] _hasPermission: YES

...

2020-01-19 17:09:22.821477+0100 myApp[8896:2663036] PUSH_TOKEN: IOS_TOKEN: d2aac51a963530-FULL_TOKEN_HERE
2020-01-19 17:09:22.821807+0100 myApp[8896:2663036] PUSH_TOKEN: GET_TOKEN:  frWxHosY-gQ:APA91bEk3-FULL_TOKEN_HERE

...

2020-01-19 17:13:46.395935+0100 myApp[8896:2663036] FCM direct channel = true
2020-01-19 17:15:39.418759+0100 myApp[8896:2663036] FCM direct channel = false
```

I'm running my app in debug env.

**Current behavior:**

Android:

1. Getting push messages only when app working is closed (im not using app) - it is possible to get push when app is running?

iOS:

2. Only getting APNS token, push will not showing. I checked double Settings -> notifications -> myApp Name -> everything is enabled. In Firebase console im using both tokens (from IOS_TOKEN and GET_TOKEN) both not working.

iOS: 13.3 (17C54)

xCode: 11.3 (11C29)

"cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^7.0.1"

What should i do to start receiving pushes on iOS?

Comment: In android its normal to not show push notification on foreground.but if you made a toast on notification recieved event,then a toast or abdthing you put will be trigered, or you could make a local notification containg the recieved data from notification and set themcto the local notification and then will be triggered in the foreground also.

Comment: In ios maybe your putting the GoogleService-Info.plist in a wrong directory so the notification when trigerred from the firebase api, its not finding its destination on the device .

Comment: i'll check GoogleService-info, thanks for advice. It's working because other services from google (analytics, database, crashlytics) working.

Comment: Hmmm ok ,if you console log the event when notification recieved on ios,will it log(that even if notification not shown i mean) ??

Comment: only at Android i can see message received event

Comment: In the xCode Console you said an event is being recieved right or am i wrong?

Comment: not. Everything i got in xcode console is it my post above :)

Comment: Ok,i usually use oneSignal as messaging and sometimes firebase but i don't remember the firebase code exactly,i will send you a link i found now but i am not sure if this code let the notification be recieved in background(maybe its just forground and maybe i didn't give the articale much time to read) and if it didn't work as you want just rensend a comment and tomorow when i get my computer i'll send the code.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-push-notifications-working-with-ionic-4-and-firebase-ad87cc92394e/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I forgot to upload my .p8 key to firebase.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Lesson learnt: always read documentation :)